# Paypal Plugin sending payment to wrong receiver

Tags: plugins, paypal, joomla

This is not my code***
I am using an open source plugin on a site I am trying to develop. It is a crowdfunding platform and this plugin is suppose to allow payments to be sent directly to project creators. But when I run payment tests in sandbox all payments are being sent to site owner.

I already tried changing the lines in the //prepare payment receiver & //get payment receiver areas from site_owner to project_owner but that did nothing.

I have tried the plugin developer already but haven't heard back so thought I'd see if anyone here could shed some light on the problem for me.

Thanks for any help you can give.

```
use Crowdfunding\Transaction\Transaction;
use Crowdfunding\Transaction\TransactionManager;
use Crowdfunding\Reward;
use Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper;

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('Prism.init');
jimport('Crowdfunding.init');
jimport('Crowdfundingfinance.init');
jimport('Emailtemplates.init');

JObserverMapper::addObserverClassToClass(
    'Crowdfunding\\Observer\\Transaction\\TransactionObserver',
    'Crowdfunding\\Transaction\\TransactionManager',
    array('typeAlias' => 'com_crowdfunding.payment')
);

/**
 * Crowdfunding PayPal payment plugin.
 *
 * @package      Crowdfunding
 * @subpackage   Plugins
 */
class plgCrowdfundingPaymentPayPal extends Crowdfunding\Payment\Plugin
{
    public function __construct(&$subject, $config = array())
    {
        $this->serviceProvider = 'PayPal';
        $this->serviceAlias    = 'paypal';

        $this->extraDataKeys = array(
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'payer_id', 'payer_status',
            'mc_gross', 'mc_fee', 'mc_currency', 'payment_status', 'payment_type', 'payment_date',
            'txn_type', 'test_ipn', 'ipn_track_id', 'custom', 'protection_eligibility'
        );

        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
    }

    /**
     * This method prepares a payment gateway - buttons, forms,...
     * That gateway will be displayed on the summary page as a payment option.
     *
     * @param string    $context This string gives information about that where it has been executed the trigger.
     * @param stdClass  $item    A project data.
     * @param Joomla\Registry\Registry $params  The parameters of the component
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws \UnexpectedValueException
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function onProjectPayment($context, $item, $params)
    {
        if (strcmp('com_crowdfunding.payment', $context) !== 0) {
            return null;
        }

        if ($this->app->isAdmin()) {
            return null;
        }

        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
        /**  @var $doc JDocumentHtml */

        // Check document type
        $docType = $doc->getType();
        if (strcmp('html', $docType) !== 0) {
            return null;
        }

        // This is a URI path to the plugin folder
        $pluginURI = 'plugins/crowdfundingpayment/paypal';

        $notifyUrl = $this->getCallbackUrl();
        $returnUrl = $this->getReturnUrl($item->slug, $item->catslug);
        $cancelUrl = $this->getCancelUrl($item->slug, $item->catslug);

        // DEBUG DATA
        JDEBUG ? $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_DEBUG_NOTIFY_URL'), $this->debugType, $notifyUrl) : null;
        JDEBUG ? $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_DEBUG_RETURN_URL'), $this->debugType, $returnUrl) : null;
        JDEBUG ? $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_DEBUG_CANCEL_URL'), $this->debugType, $cancelUrl) : null;

        $html   = array();
        $html[] = '<div class="well">';

        $html[] = '<h4><img src="' . $pluginURI . '/images/paypal_icon.png" width="36" height="32" alt="PayPal" />' . JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_TITLE') . '</h4>';

        // Prepare payment receiver.
        $paymentReceiverOption = $this->params->get('paypal_payment_receiver', 'site_owner');
        $paymentReceiverInput = $this->preparePaymentReceiver($paymentReceiverOption, $item->id);
        if ($paymentReceiverInput === null) {
            $html[] = $this->generateSystemMessage(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_ERROR_PAYMENT_RECEIVER_MISSING'));
            return implode("\n", $html);
        }

        // Display additional information.
        $html[] = '<p>' . JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_INFO') . '</p>';

        // Start the form.
        if ($this->params->get('paypal_sandbox', 1)) {
            $html[] = '<form action="' . trim($this->params->get('paypal_sandbox_url')) . '" method="post">';
        } else {
            $html[] = '<form action="' . trim($this->params->get('paypal_url')) . '" method="post">';
        }

        $html[] = $paymentReceiverInput;

        $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />';
        $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" />';
        $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="' . $item->currencyCode . '" />';
        $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="' . $item->amount . '" />';
        $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />';
        $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />';
        $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />';
        $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0" />';

        // Title
        $title  = JText::sprintf($this->textPrefix . '_INVESTING_IN_S', htmlentities($item->title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="' . $title . '" />';

        // Get payment session
        $paymentSessionContext    = Crowdfunding\Constants::PAYMENT_SESSION_CONTEXT . $item->id;
        $paymentSessionLocal      = $this->app->getUserState($paymentSessionContext);

        $paymentSessionRemote = $this->getPaymentSession(array(
            'session_id'    => $paymentSessionLocal->session_id
        ));

        // Prepare custom data
        $custom = array(
            'payment_session_id' => $paymentSessionRemote->getId(),
            'gateway'            => $this->serviceAlias
        );

        $custom = base64_encode(json_encode($custom));
        $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $custom . '" />';

        // Set a link to logo
        $imageUrl = trim($this->params->get('paypal_image_url'));
        if ($imageUrl) {
            $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="' . $imageUrl . '" />';
        }

        // Set URLs
        $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="' . $cancelUrl . '" />';
        $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="return" value="' . $returnUrl . '" />';
        $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="' . $notifyUrl . '" />';

        $this->prepareLocale($html);

        // End the form.
        $html[] = '<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >';
        $html[] = '</form>';

        // Display a sticky note if the extension works in sandbox mode.
        if ($this->params->get('paypal_sandbox', 1)) {
            $html[] = '<div class="bg-info p-10-5"><span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span> ' . JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_WORKS_SANDBOX') . '</div>';
        }

        $html[] = '</div>';

        return implode("\n", $html);
    }

    /**
     * This method processes transaction data that comes from PayPal instant notifier.
     *
     * @param string    $context This string gives information about that where it has been executed the trigger.
     * @param Joomla\Registry\Registry $params  The parameters of the component
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws \OutOfBoundsException
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     * @throws \UnexpectedValueException
     *
     * @return null|stdClass
     */
    public function onPaymentNotify($context, $params)
    {
        if (strcmp('com_crowdfunding.notify.'.$this->serviceAlias, $context) !== 0) {
            return null;
        }

        if ($this->app->isAdmin()) {
            return null;
        }

        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
        /**  @var $doc JDocumentHtml */

        // Check document type
        $docType = $doc->getType();
        if (strcmp('raw', $docType) !== 0) {
            return null;
        }

        // Validate request method
        $requestMethod = $this->app->input->getMethod();
        if (strcmp('POST', $requestMethod) !== 0) {
            $this->log->add(
                JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_ERROR_INVALID_REQUEST_METHOD'),
                $this->debugType,
                JText::sprintf($this->textPrefix . '_ERROR_INVALID_TRANSACTION_REQUEST_METHOD', $requestMethod)
            );

            return null;
        }

        // DEBUG DATA
        JDEBUG ? $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_DEBUG_RESPONSE'), $this->debugType, $_POST) : null;

        // Decode custom data
        $custom = ArrayHelper::getValue($_POST, 'custom');
        $custom = json_decode(base64_decode($custom), true);

        // DEBUG DATA
        JDEBUG ? $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_DEBUG_CUSTOM'), $this->debugType, $custom) : null;

        // Verify gateway. Is it PayPal?
        $gateway = ArrayHelper::getValue($custom, 'gateway');
        if (!$this->isValidPaymentGateway($gateway)) {
            $this->log->add(
                JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_ERROR_INVALID_PAYMENT_GATEWAY'),
                $this->debugType,
                array('custom' => $custom, '_POST' => $_POST)
            );

            return null;
        }

        // Get PayPal URL
        if ($this->params->get('paypal_sandbox', 1)) {
            $url = trim($this->params->get('paypal_sandbox_url', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'));
        } else {
            $url = trim($this->params->get('paypal_url', 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'));
        }

        $paypalIpn       = new Prism\Payment\PayPal\Ipn($url, $_POST);
        $loadCertificate = (bool)$this->params->get('paypal_load_certificate', 0);
        $paypalIpn->verify($loadCertificate);

        // DEBUG DATA
        JDEBUG ? $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_DEBUG_VERIFY_OBJECT'), $this->debugType, $paypalIpn) : null;

        // Prepare the array that have to be returned by this method.
        $paymentResult = new stdClass;
        $paymentResult->project         = null;
        $paymentResult->reward          = null;
        $paymentResult->transaction     = null;
        $paymentResult->paymentSession  = null;
        $paymentResult->serviceProvider = $this->serviceProvider;
        $paymentResult->serviceAlias    = $this->serviceAlias;

        if ($paypalIpn->isVerified()) {
            $containerHelper  = new Crowdfunding\Container\Helper();
            $currency         = $containerHelper->fetchCurrency($this->container, $params);

            // Get payment session data
            $paymentSessionId       = ArrayHelper::getValue($custom, 'payment_session_id', 0, 'int');
            $paymentSessionRemote   = $this->getPaymentSession(array('id' => $paymentSessionId));

            // Check for valid payment session.
            if (!$paymentSessionRemote->getId()) {
                $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_ERROR_PAYMENT_SESSION'), $this->errorType, $paymentSessionRemote->getProperties());
                return null;
            }

            // DEBUG DATA
            JDEBUG ? $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_DEBUG_PAYMENT_SESSION'), $this->debugType, $paymentSessionRemote->getProperties()) : null;

            // Validate transaction data
            $validData = $this->validateData($_POST, $currency->getCode(), $paymentSessionRemote);
            if ($validData === null) {
                return null;
            }

            // DEBUG DATA
            JDEBUG ? $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_DEBUG_VALID_DATA'), $this->debugType, $validData) : null;

            // Set the receiver ID.
            $project = $containerHelper->fetchProject($this->container, $validData['project_id']);
            $validData['receiver_id'] = $project->getUserId();

            // Get reward object.
            $reward = null;
            if ($validData['reward_id']) {
                $reward = $containerHelper->fetchReward($this->container, $validData['reward_id'], $project->getId());
            }

            // Save transaction data.
            // If it is not completed, return empty results.
            // If it is complete, continue with process transaction data
            $transaction = $this->storeTransaction($validData);
            if ($transaction === null) {
                return null;
            }

            // Generate object of data, based on the transaction properties.
            $paymentResult->transaction = $transaction;

            // Generate object of data based on the project properties.
            $paymentResult->project = $project;

            // Generate object of data based on the reward properties.
            if ($reward !== null and ($reward instanceof Crowdfunding\Reward)) {
                $paymentResult->reward = $reward;
            }

            // Generate data object, based on the payment session properties.
            $paymentResult->paymentSession = $paymentSessionRemote;

            // Removing intention.
            $this->removeIntention($paymentSessionRemote, $transaction);
        } else {
            // Log error
            $this->log->add(
                JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_ERROR_INVALID_TRANSACTION_DATA'),
                $this->debugType,
                array('ERROR MESSAGE' => $paypalIpn->getError(), 'paypalVerify' => $paypalIpn, '_POST' => $_POST)
            );
        }

        return $paymentResult;
    }

    /**
     * Validate PayPal transaction.
     *
     * @param array  $data
     * @param string $currencyCode
     * @param Crowdfunding\Payment\Session  $paymentSessionRemote
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     * @return array
     */
    protected function validateData($data, $currencyCode, $paymentSessionRemote)
    {
        $txnDate = ArrayHelper::getValue($data, 'payment_date');
        $date    = new JDate($txnDate);

        // Prepare transaction data
        $transactionData = array(
            'investor_id'      => $paymentSessionRemote->getUserId(),
            'project_id'       => $paymentSessionRemote->getProjectId(),
            'reward_id'        => $paymentSessionRemote->isAnonymous() ? 0 : $paymentSessionRemote->getRewardId(),
            'service_provider' => $this->serviceProvider,
            'service_alias'    => $this->serviceAlias,
            'txn_id'           => ArrayHelper::getValue($data, 'txn_id', null, 'string'),
            'txn_amount'       => ArrayHelper::getValue($data, 'mc_gross', null, 'float'),
            'txn_currency'     => ArrayHelper::getValue($data, 'mc_currency', null, 'string'),
            'txn_status'       => strtolower(ArrayHelper::getValue($data, 'payment_status', '', 'string')),
            'txn_date'         => $date->toSql(),
            'extra_data'       => $this->prepareExtraData($data)
        );

        // Check Project ID and Transaction ID
        if (!$transactionData['project_id'] or !$transactionData['txn_id']) {
            $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_ERROR_INVALID_TRANSACTION_DATA'), $this->errorType, $transactionData);
            return null;
        }

        // Check if project record exists in database.
        $projectRecord = new Crowdfunding\Validator\Project\Record(JFactory::getDbo(), $transactionData['project_id']);
        if (!$projectRecord->isValid()) {
            $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_ERROR_INVALID_PROJECT'), $this->errorType, $transactionData);
            return null;
        }

        // Check if reward record exists in database.
        if ($transactionData['reward_id'] > 0) {
            $rewardRecord = new Crowdfunding\Validator\Reward\Record(JFactory::getDbo(), $transactionData['reward_id'], array('state' => Prism\Constants::PUBLISHED));
            if (!$rewardRecord->isValid()) {
                $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_ERROR_INVALID_REWARD'), $this->errorType, $transactionData);
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Check currency
        if (strcmp($transactionData['txn_currency'], $currencyCode) !== 0) {
            $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_ERROR_INVALID_TRANSACTION_CURRENCY'), $this->errorType, array('TRANSACTION DATA' => $transactionData, 'CURRENCY' => $currencyCode));
            return null;
        }

        // Check payment receiver.
        $allowedReceivers = array(
            strtolower(ArrayHelper::getValue($data, 'business')),
            strtolower(ArrayHelper::getValue($data, 'receiver_email')),
            strtolower(ArrayHelper::getValue($data, 'receiver_id'))
        );

        // Get payment receiver.
        $paymentReceiverOption = $this->params->get('paypal_payment_receiver', 'site_owner');
        $paymentReceiver       = $this->getPaymentReceiver($paymentReceiverOption, $transactionData['project_id']);

        if (!in_array($paymentReceiver, $allowedReceivers, true)) {
            $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_ERROR_INVALID_RECEIVER'), $this->errorType, array('TRANSACTION DATA' => $transactionData, 'RECEIVER' => $paymentReceiver, 'ALLOWED RECEIVERS' => $allowedReceivers));
            return null;
        }

        return $transactionData;
    }

    /**
     * Save transaction data.
     *
     * @param array     $transactionData
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws \UnexpectedValueException
     *
     * @return Transaction|null
     */
    protected function storeTransaction($transactionData)
    {
        // Get transaction object by transaction ID
        $keys  = array(
            'txn_id' => ArrayHelper::getValue($transactionData, 'txn_id')
        );
        $transaction = new Transaction(JFactory::getDbo());
        $transaction->load($keys);

        // DEBUG DATA
        JDEBUG ? $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_DEBUG_TRANSACTION_OBJECT'), $this->debugType, $transaction->getProperties()) : null;

        // Check for existed transaction
        // If the current status if completed, stop the payment process.
        if ($transaction->getId() and $transaction->isCompleted()) {
            return null;
        }

        // Add extra data.
        if (array_key_exists('extra_data', $transactionData)) {
            if (!empty($transactionData['extra_data'])) {
                $transaction->addExtraData($transactionData['extra_data']);
            }

            unset($transactionData['extra_data']);
        }

        // IMPORTANT: It must be before ->bind();
        $options = array(
            'old_status' => $transaction->getStatus(),
            'new_status' => $transactionData['txn_status']
        );

        // Create the new transaction record if there is not record.
        // If there is new record, store new data with new status.
        // Example: It has been 'pending' and now is 'completed'.
        // Example2: It has been 'pending' and now is 'failed'.
        $transaction->bind($transactionData);

        // Start database transaction.
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $db->transactionStart();

        try {
            $transactionManager = new TransactionManager($db);
            $transactionManager->setTransaction($transaction);
            $transactionManager->process('com_crowdfunding.payment', $options);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $db->transactionRollback();

            $this->log->add(JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_ERROR_TRANSACTION_PROCESS'), $this->errorType, $e->getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        // Commit database transaction.
        $db->transactionCommit();

        return $transaction;
    }

    protected function prepareLocale(&$html)
    {
        // Get country
        $countryId = $this->params->get('paypal_country');
        $country   = new Crowdfunding\Country(JFactory::getDbo());
        $country->load($countryId);

        $code  = $country->getCode();
        $code4 = $country->getLocale();

        $button    = $this->params->get('paypal_button_type', 'btn_buynow_LG');
        $buttonUrl = $this->params->get('paypal_button_url');

        // Generate a button
        if (!$this->params->get('paypal_button_default', 0)) {
            if (!$buttonUrl) {
                if (strcmp('US', $code) === 0) {
                    $html[] = '<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/' . $code4 . '/i/btn/' . $button . '.gif" alt="' . JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_BUTTON_ALT') . '">';
                } else {
                    $html[] = '<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/' . $code4 . '/' . $code . '/i/btn/' . $button . '.gif" alt="' . JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_BUTTON_ALT') . '">';
                }
            } else {
                $html[] = '<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="' . $buttonUrl . '" alt="' . JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_BUTTON_ALT') . '">';
            }
        } else { // Default button
            $html[] = '<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/' . $button . '.gif" alt="' . JText::_($this->textPrefix . '_BUTTON_ALT') . '">';
        }

        // Set locale
        $html[] = '<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="' . $code . '" />';
    }

    /**
     * Prepare a form element of payment receiver.
     *
     * @param $paymentReceiverOption
     * @param $itemId
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    protected function preparePaymentReceiver($paymentReceiverOption, $itemId)
    {
        if ($this->params->get('paypal_sandbox', 1)) {
            return '<input type="hidden" name="business" value="' . trim($this->params->get('paypal_sandbox_business_name')) . '" />';
        } else {
            if (strcmp('site_owner', $paymentReceiverOption) === 0) { // Site owner
                return '<input type="hidden" name="business" value="' . trim($this->params->get('paypal_business_name')) . '" />';
            } else {
                if (!JComponentHelper::isEnabled('com_crowdfundingfinance')) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    $payout = new Crowdfundingfinance\Payout(JFactory::getDbo());
                    $payout->load(array('project_id' => $itemId));

                    if (!$payout->getPaypalEmail()) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    return '<input type="hidden" name="business" value="' . trim($payout->getPaypalEmail()) . '" />';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return payment receiver.
     *
     * @param $paymentReceiverOption
     * @param $itemId
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    protected function getPaymentReceiver($paymentReceiverOption, $itemId)
    {
        if ($this->params->get('paypal_sandbox', 1)) {
            return strtolower(trim($this->params->get('paypal_sandbox_business_name')));
        } else {
            if (strcmp('site_owner', $paymentReceiverOption) === 0) { // Site owner
                return strtolower(trim($this->params->get('paypal_business_name')));
            } else {
                if (!JComponentHelper::isEnabled('com_crowdfundingfinance')) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    $payout = new Crowdfundingfinance\Payout(JFactory::getDbo());
                    $payout->load(array('project_id' => $itemId));

                    if (!$payout->getPaypalEmail()) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    return strtolower(trim($payout->getPaypalEmail()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem lies here

```
$paymentReceiverOption = $this->params->get('paypal_payment_receiver', 'site_owner');
```

There must be some plugin settings at the backend that overrides any change you do in the code. Suppose that plugin params are stored with different data then only that data will be considered, even if you change it to `project_owner`.

Can you send more details of that plugin, plugin name, plugin parameters and also I feel you can write the post variables to a text file before being submitted, to know exactly where the problem lies.

You are probably using ITPrism Crowdfunding plugin. There if you see the XML file, you get this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.6" type="plugin" group="crowdfundingpayment" method="upgrade">
    <name>PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL</name>
    <author>Todor Iliev</author>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2016 Todor Iliev ( ITPrism.com ). All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html GNU/GPLv3</license>
    <authorEmail>todor@itprism.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>http://itprism.com</authorUrl>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <creationDate>09 November, 2016</creationDate>
    <description><![CDATA[
    <p>Crowdfunding Payment - PayPal is a plugin that provides ability for making payments via PayPal Payments Standard method.</p>
    <p><a href='http://itprism.com/' target='_blank'>Subscribe for the newsletter</a> to receive information about updates and new ITPrism extensions.</p>
    <p>Please, <a href='http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/e-commerce/donations/crowdfunding' target='_blank'>vote for the extension</a> on Joomla! Extensions Directory</p>
    ]]></description>

    <help url="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_HELP_URL"/>

    <files>
        <filename plugin="paypal">paypal.php</filename>

        <folder>images</folder>
        <folder>language</folder>
    </files>

    <config>

        <fields name="params" addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_crowdfunding/models/fields">
            <fieldset name="basic">
                <field name="paypal_business_name" type="text" size="80" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_MERCHANT_ID" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_MERCHANT_ID_DESC" />
                <field name="paypal_url" type="text" size="80" default="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_PAYPAL_URL" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_PAYPAL_URL_DESC" class="span6" />
                <field name="return_url" type="text" size="80" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_RETURN_URL" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_RETURN_URL_DESC" class="span6" />
                <field name="cancel_url" type="text" size="80" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_CANCEL_URL" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_CANCEL_URL_DESC" class="span6" />
                <field name="callback_url" type="text" default="index.php?option=com_crowdfunding&amp;task=notifier.notify&amp;format=raw&amp;payment_service=paypal" size="80" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_NOTIFY_URL" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_NOTIFY_URL_DESC" class="span6" />
                <field name="paypal_country" type="cfcountries" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_COUNTRY" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_COUNTRY_DESC" required="true" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset name="sandbox" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_SANDBOX">
                <field name="paypal_sandbox" type="radio" default="1" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_ENABLE_SANDBOX" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_SANDBOX_DESC" class="btn-group">
                    <option value="0">JNO</option>
                    <option value="1">JYES</option>
                </field>
                <field name="paypal_sandbox_business_name" size="80" type="text" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_SANDBOX_MERCHANT_ID" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_SANDBOX_MERCHANT_ID_DESC" />
                <field name="paypal_sandbox_url" type="text" size="80" default="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_SANDBOX_URL" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_SANDBOX_URL_DESC" class="span6" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset name="emails" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_NOTIFICATION_EMAILS" addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_emailtemplates/models/fields">
                <field name="admin_mail_id" type="emailtemplate" default="0" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_SEND_MAIL_ADMIN" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_SEND_MAIL_ADMIN_DESC" class="btn-group" />
                <field name="creator_mail_id" type="emailtemplate" default="0" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_SEND_MAIL_CREATOR" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_SEND_MAIL_CREATOR_DESC" class="btn-group" />
                <field name="user_mail_id" type="emailtemplate" default="0" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_SEND_MAIL_USER" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_SEND_MAIL_USER_DESC" class="btn-group" />

                <field name="email_mode" type="list" default="html" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_EMAIL_MODE" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_EMAIL_MODE_DESC" >
                   <option value="plain">PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_PLAIN</option>
                   <option value="html">PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_HTML</option>
                </field>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset name="advanced">
                <field name="paypal_image_url" type="text" default="" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_LOGO_URL" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_LOGO_URL_DESC" size="80" class="span6" />
                <field name="paypal_button_default" type="radio" default="0" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_DEFAULT_BUTTON" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_DEFAULT_BUTTON_DESC" class="btn-group">
                    <option value="0">JNO</option>
                    <option value="1">JYES</option>
                </field>
                <field name="paypal_button_type" type="list" default="html" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_BUTTON_TYPE" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_BUTTON_TYPE_DESC" >
                   <option value="btn_buynow_LG">PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_BUY_NOW</option>
                   <option value="btn_buynowCC_LG">PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_BUY_NOW_CC</option>
                   <option value="btn_paynow_LG">PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_PAY_NOW</option>
                   <option value="btn_paynowCC_LG">PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_PAY_NOW_CC</option>
                   <option value="btn_donate_LG">PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_DONATE</option>
                   <option value="btn_donateCC_LG">PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_DONATE_CC</option>
                </field>
                <field name="paypal_button_url" type="text" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_BUTTON_URL" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_BUTTON_URL_DESC" class="span6" size="80" />
                <field name="paypal_load_certificate" type="radio" default="0" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_LOAD_CERTIFICATE" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_LOAD_CERTIFICATE_DESC" class="btn-group">
                    <option value="0">JNO</option>
                    <option value="1">JYES</option>
                </field>

                <field name="paypal_payment_receiver" type="list" default="site_owner" label="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_PAYMENT_RECEIVER" description="PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_PAYMENT_RECEIVER_DESC">
                    <option value="site_owner">PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_SITE_OWNER</option>
                    <option value="project_owner">PLG_CROWDFUNDINGPAYMENT_PAYPAL_PROJECT_OWNER</option>
                </field>
            </fieldset>
        </fields>

    </config>
</extension>
```

If you look at the end field there is paypal_payment_receiver. This is the setting to be entered at the backend. Login to your administrator and then open plugin manager. Search for paypal crowdfunding plugin. Set the parameter to project owner. Remember I am not asking you to change the code. This is more easy than changing your code.

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking me to send you... I already copied the whole plugin code

Comment: @salvador5266 I asked the plugin name but I was able to find out through the codes. Anyways I have edited my answer and added relevant parts that can help you.